# DateTime conversion problems in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

I have the following SQL snippet:

```
WHERE YEAR(wo.audt_created_dttm) >= 2011 - 3 --narrows down to a year
AND YEAR(wo.audt_created_dttm) >= 2006 -- bad data less than 2006
AND wo.audt_created_dttm < DATEADD(mm, 1, CAST(CAST(1 * 3 as varchar) + '/01/' +  CAST(2011 as varchar) as DateTime))
```

which I translated into LINQ to SQL (for testing purposes in LINQPad) like this:

```
int year = 2012, quarter = 1;
DateTime timeframe = new DateTime(year, (quarter * 3), 01).AddMonths(1); 


where wo.Audt_created_dttm.Value.Year >= year - 3 && wo.Audt_created_dttm.Value.Year >= 2006
    && wo.Audt_created_dttm < timeframe && (s.Id =="NM" || s.Id == "TH") && 
    (wo.Clsdt_date ?? new DateTime(3000, 01, 01)) < DateTime.Now
```

However, for the actual solution I do not want to specifically define the year or quarter.  I want the year and quarter to be current.

For the year, I tried to do this:

```
DateTime timeframe = new DateTime(timeframe.Year, (quarter * 3), 01).AddMonths(1);
```

but the compiler doesn't like that at all.  Then I tried this:

```
DateTime setYear = new DateTime();
DateTime timeframe = new DateTime(setYear.Year, (quarter * 3), 01).AddMonths(1)
```

that didn't work either. I'm at a loss for how to do either the year or the quarter and would appreciate any advice

Comment: How exactly did it not work? What *did* it do?

Comment: Tried your code, seems to work without compilation errors.

Comment: @ svick - It worked fine if I kept the year and quarter data types and had them set to a specific year and quarter.  However, I did not want a specific year or quarter.  I only specifically set them so that I could test my LINQ to SQL code in LINQPad to ensure my output was correct.  Both timeframe.Year and setYear.Year gave me a "field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property" blah, blah, blah.  I have found the answer.

Comment: @ Magnus - Yes it worked fine when I had the year and quarter set to a specific year and quarter.  I found the answer.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want the year and quarter to be current.

To get the first day of the current quarter you can use this code:

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
var quarter = (now.Month - 1)/3;
var timeframe = new DateTime(now.Year, 3*quarter + 1, 1);
```

`timeframe` will contain 2012-04-01, 2012-07-01, 2012-10-01 etc. depending on the current date.

Comment: @ Martin Liversage: Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Do you want the current year?

```
  DateTime.Today.Year
```